# SQLObject: Как удалить один объект из MultipleJoin/RelatedJoin?

Tags: python, orm

Пример:

```
class A(SQLObject):
    b = ForeignKey('B')

class B(SQLObject):
    a = MultipleJoin('A', joinColumn='b')

b1 = B()  
a1 = A(bID=b1)  
a2 = A(bID=b1)
```

А как же удалить ненужный, предположим, `a2`?

Answer (score 0):

Добавление и удаление объектов в поля `MultipleJoin` и `RelatedJoin` производится посредством автоматически генерируемых методов `add<НазваниеПоля>` и `remove<НазваниеПоля>`. 
Нужно было внимательнее читать документацию..